# does components in codenameone carry resizable behavior

Tags: codenameone

Does components in codenameone have resizable behavior or pinch zooming. For eg. If I want to zoom in Table to see values closely or resize it from bottom.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes see: http://www.codenameone.com/blog/in-a-pinch

This will work for components like `MapComponent` & `ImageViewer`. For other components you will need to subclass and override the pinch callback.

Comment: I saw pinch code  for `ImageViewer` but no idea how to proceed with `Table` component .

Comment: I get the overriding `pinch(float scale)`  part but how to update Table ui is not so clear.

Comment: That depends on how you want pinch to behave in table? There is no zoom functionality builtin to arbitrary components.

Comment: Say, just like pinch zooming in photograph and every cell in table should zoom in equal proportion.

Comment: That's not something that would be trivial to accomplish. Usually when developers implemented zoom support for components they enlarged the font to create the effect of zooming. Unlike an image where we can just draw it with a different scale components are more complex since you need pointer events etc. to land in the right place. Its possible but I think the complexity is a bit beyond an answer on StackOverflow.